# "Давиденко Инна" - склонение

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Подскажите пожалуйста как будет "Давиденко Инна" в родительном падеже? Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Фамилия Давиденко (и мужская, и женская) не склоняется. В родительном падеже будет: *Давиденко Инны*.